# Retrieve values of input fields from a table containing input fields as its data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, html-table

**Scenario :**

- I have a table containing input fields and the number of input fields are not fixed, it can any number as the table is being rendered everytime based on what data user wants from the database.
- So, every the table is rendered,each row of table has 5 input fields
  as :

  > ```
  >      <input name="t-1">
  >      <input name="r-1">
  >      <input name="q-1">
  >      <input name="s-1">
  >      <input name="p-1">
  > ```
- The next row of table has again 5 input fields simliar to first row but the count number in the name for each input filed is incremented by 1.

  > ```
  >     <input name="t-2">
  >     <input name="r-2">
  >     <input name="q-2">
  >     <input name="s-2">
  >     <input name="p-2">
  > ```

So for each row , the count number is incremented by 1 as per row number.
The user can modify and post the table to update database.

**Todo :**

- I want to retrieve values of all these input fields while the form table is posted for updation. 

  **Is there any easy way to achieve this ?**

Please suggest.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you have any code for this work?

Comment: @Mohammad As of know ,I don't. I am on it, trying to write the code.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/om1nxe7g/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do add a class to every input you're interested in. For example `data-field`.

So each input would look like this

`<input class="data-field" name="...">`

Then just loop through them adding the values to whatever data structure you'd like to use, here I'll just use a list

```
var data = [];
$(".data-field").each((index, element) => { 
   data.push(element.value);
})
```

You can then perform whatever server request you need to make using the contents of `data` as your payload.

However, if you intend to just use a HTML form. Just ensuring that all inputs are within the form body and have name fields which are unique should suffice.

They should be automatically included in your form's payload.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is your friend.
It allows you to leverage [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

- `document.querySelectorAll("input[name*='-1']")` for querying the first row
- `document.querySelectorAll("input[name*='r-']")` for querying the first column

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov90ecsf/).

*No classes were harmed*.